# Problems trying to export a vector into a geojson

Tags: python, export, date

we have a problem when trying to export vectors that contains attributes that have double / in their name. Our attribute looks like a date:
1/1/21 and even if we try to convert it to string qgis still sees it as date when it gets exported and modifies it.

Is there any way around this?

This seems to happen only when exporting to geojson and not to shp file.

Here is a sample of a geojson file that the attributes get altered when we open it in qgis. Just open it up in qgis and check the attribute table. And yes we know that geojson doesn't have attribute type, we trying to find a way around it.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "x123",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id1": "1/1/21", "id2": "1/2/13" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ ] } }
]
}
```

Comment: If the the vector data that you want to export is not shapefile, then what is the vector data type?

Comment: it's geojson, when we add it back in qgis and export it...it changes the values for text to datatype

Comment: Could you provide a small sample for testing?

Comment: there's no need for a sample it's a feature of qgis that we try to get around. Any geojson that have the date format in the attribute tables when we open it and export it back it modifies that field to a date type format. And we want it to remain the same.

Comment: I would like to find a workaround or solution for you and with test data it would be a bit easier. It would also help to understand what happens to your data. JSON does not have date type https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp so I guess that the strings are altered somehow.

Comment: @user30184 I added a sample file of a geojson if that helps. Just import it back in qgis and you will see the attributes get changed

Comment: Thank you for the sample, it did speed up testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That some kind of strings are converted into dates in QGIS comes from the GDAL GeoJSON driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html.

Because JSON does not have a special datatype for date/datetime the driver automatically maps strings which use common date/datetime structure into corresponding data types.

> Schema detection will recognize fields of type String, Integer, Real,
> StringList, IntegerList and RealList, Integer(Boolean), Date, Time and
> DateTime.

Fortunately there is an open option https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html#open-options that keeps date-alike strings as strings if needed.

> DATE_AS_STRING = YES/NO: (GDAL >= 3.0.3) Whether to expose
> date/time/date-time content using dedicated OGR date/time/date-time
> types or as a OGR String. Default is NO (that is date/time/date-time
> are detected as such). Can also be set with the
> OGR_GEOJSON_DATE_AS_STRING configuration option.

Test with your sample:

```
ogrinfo datetest.json -al -oo DATE_AS_STRING=YES

INFO: Open of `datetest.json'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: x123
Geometry: Multi Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
id1: String (0.0)
id2: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(x123):0
  id1 (String) = 1/1/21
  id2 (String) = 1/2/13
  MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY
```

In QGIS the option is at the bottom of the GeoJSON options

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a general option for importing geojson files all the time by drag and drop and having the Date_As_String as Yes by Default? And thank you for the answer above is the correct one.

Comment: Set environmental variable `OGR_GEOJSON_DATE_AS_STRING=YES`.